# Как заполнить свободное пространство в header?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как заполнить данное пустое пространство? `Padding`?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Заполнить чем? И зачем?

Comment: Наверное нужно сделать отступ до и после "WEB & GRAPHICS..."?
Тогда используйте или margin у блока с текстом или padding у контейнера..... или, кстати можно уже flexbox юзать!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вы можете дать блоку высоту:

```
<div style="height:600px;"><div style="line-height:600px"></div></div>
```

Дать отступы padding:

```
<div style="height:600px;"><div style="width:300px;height:40px;padding:280px;position:relative;left:50%;margin-left:-150px;"></div></div>
```

или margin:

```
<div style="height:600px;"><div style="height:40px;margin:280px auto;"></div></div>
```

Да и вообще способов уйма. Если вам интересен способ именно того сайта - нажмите F12 и посмотрите CSS стили.

Answer (score 0):

Контейнеру дать высоту 100%/100vh и сделать его:
.container {
Display: flex; 
Align-items: center;
Justify-content: center
}